# Julia Jump Xpress.jl XPRESSDIR environment variable for installation

Tags: environment-variables, julia-jump, xpress-optimizer

In my .zshenv I've tried adding an environment variable by adding the following line

export XPRESSDIR='/Applications/FICO\ Xpress/Xpress\ Workbench.app/Contents/Resources/xpressmp'

I've also tried

export XPRESSDIR='/Applications/FICO\ Xpress/xpressmp'

But each time I Pkg.build("Xpress"), I get an error message telling me about my environment variable for XPRESSDIR

ERROR: Error building `Xpress`:
ERROR: LoadError: Unable to locate Xpress installation.
Please check your enviroment variable XPRESSDIR.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Problem: Environment variable not being loaded properly

Is the environment variable being loaded into Julia?

In a Julia session, run

```
import Pkg
ENV["XPRESSDIR"] = "/Applications/FICO Xpress/xpressmp"
Pkg.add("Xpress")
Pkg.build("Xpress")
```

### Problem: path is incorrect

On some mac installations, the path should be
`/Users/[USER-NAME]/Applications/fico-xpress/xpressmp`. You should check where Xpress is installed. It needs to be set so that `%XPRESSDIR%/lib/libxprs.dylib` is a file.

Comment: THis did the trick. Thanks so much.